# Can I make the grid size in fmsb radarchart smaller?

Tags: r, radar-chart

I am currently trying to build a radar chart with my data. The maximum value of one group is 6.77, so I would like the grid to go up to 7. However, it seems to go up to 20, so all my plot data looks really close together and is not filling the grid [image: please see the image of the radar chart]

```
library(fmsb)

Aims <- data.frame(
  row.names = c("Lose_Weight", "Avoid_Gaining", "No_Aims", "Gain_Weight"),
  Reactive = c(3.56768, 3.3205, 3.0144, 3.035),
  Neg_Emotional = c(3.9405, 3.6918, 3.0849, 2.9731),
  Positive = c(1.9264, 1.9629, 1.8804, 2.2143),
  Restricted = c(2.8754, 2.85912, 1.9621, 1.76222),
  Homeostatic = c(3.358, 3.5522, 3.7028, 3.6611)
)
Aims

# Define the variable ranges: maximum and minimum
max_min <- data.frame(
  Reactive = c(5.9, 1.242), Neg_Emotional = c(6.77, 0.75), Positive = c(4, 1),
  Restricted = c(4.666, 0.878), Homeostatic = c(5, 1.83)
)
rownames(max_min) <- c("Max", "Min")

# Bind the variable ranges to the data
df <- rbind(max_min, Aims)
df


library(fmsb)
radarchart(df, 
           cglty = 5, 
           cglcol = "gray", 
           pcol = c("red", "purple", "blue", "green"),
           plwd = 1.5,
           plty = 1, 
           seg = 4, 
           vlcex = 1)
```